# Jaxb and Object class do not get the value from the Xml when unmarshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

I have a problem with the following source code.
After unmarshalling the "Simple" class, the property "content" created from the "content" tag is null. I mean the "content" property don't get the value "123456" from the xml.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Simple", propOrder = {
    "content"})
public class Simple extends Valor{

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=Integer.class),
    })
    protected Object content;

    //getters y setters
}
```

file.xml

```
<simple>
    <content>
        123456
    <content>
</simple>
```

Valor class

```
@XmlSeeAlso({
Varios.class,
Simple.class,
Grilla.class
})
@XmlTransient
public abstract class Valor {
    public abstract String getValorString();
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Adding some clarity to the issue I'm having. If I put the Simple class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Simple", propOrder = {
"content"})
public class Simple extends Valor{

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=Integer.class),
    })
    protected Object content;

    //getters y setters
}
```

if the xml is:

```
<simple>
<content>
    123456
</content>
</simple>
```

the output is:

```
123456
```

but if the xml is:

```
<simple>
<content>
    Hi!!
</content>
</simple>
```

the output is:

```
null
```

Now if the Simple class, exchange the XmlElements as in the following code:

```
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=Integer.class),
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class)
    })
    protected Object content;
```

if the xml is:

```
<simple>
<content>
    123456
</content>
</simple>
```

the output is:

```
null
```

but if the xml is:

```
<simple>
    <content>
        Hi!!
    </content>
</simple>
```

the output is:

```
Hi!!
```

Comment: What does your `Value` class look like?  Also when you marshal an instance of `Simple` what does the resulting XML look like?

Comment: @XmlSeeAlso({
    Varios.class,
    Simple.class,
    Grilla.class
})
@XmlTransient
public abstract class Valor {
 public abstract String getValorString();
}
I have not done the marshal, I have only done the unmarshal of a larger structure, that is why I did not put the whole code

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional info I have posted an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22914346/383861

Comment: With `@XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class)` you will be able to read both `Hi!!` and `123456` inputs, it's just that they both come in as `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce what you are seeing.  Below is what I have tried.

### Java Model

**Simple**

Below is what I implemented for your `Simple` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Simple", propOrder = {
    "content"})
public class Simple extends Valor{

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(name="content",type=Integer.class),
    })
    protected Object content;

    public Object getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValorString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void setContent(Object content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

Below is the input document with the close tag for `content` corrected.

```
<simple>
    <content>
        123456
    </content>
</simple>
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Simple.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum22911170/input.xml");
        Simple simple = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Simple.class).getValue();

        System.out.println(simple.getContent());
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
123456
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem you are running into is that you have both options in the `@XmlElements` annotation mapped to the same element `content`.  For unmarshalling JAXB will treat the element based on the first `@XmlElement` with that name.  In the case below it will always treat it as a `String`, it you reversed the order it would always treat it as an `Integer`.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="content",type=String.class),
    @XmlElement(name="content",type=Integer.class),
})
protected Object content;
```

The proper usage is to have them mapped to different elements such as

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="FOO",type=String.class),
    @XmlElement(name="BAR",type=Integer.class),
})
protected Object content;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. At first I thought it was throughout the structure that I have, but then tried the main you gave me and throws null. I corrected the item </ content>, but still not working. I do not know where can be the error.

Comment: Revisiting a little more, I saw that if the xml is <simple> <content> 123456 </ content> </ Simple> the output is: 123456, but if the xml is <simple> <content> Hi </ content! > </ Simple> I get a null

Comment: Doughan, please see the original question that I added more things for you to see what's going on

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Doughan, I always read your answers and your blog, both are very useful.